# Why can't I put a jquery-ui progressbar inside a div with fixed position?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I started the source from [this progressbar example](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar), and it works fine. My only change was to set the width of the progressbar to "20%".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 37 }).css({ width : "20%"});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="progressbar"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I then put the progressbar inside another div, and used css to fix that div in the upper-right-hand corner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <style type="text/css">
    #testContainer {
      position : fixed;
      top : 6;
      right : 6;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 37 }).css({ width : "20%"});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="testContainer">
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The progressbar becomes a slim vertical line on the left side of the screen. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to web development in general, and jquery in particular, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` property is setting the element's width to 20% *of the width of its containing block*, which is `body` in the first example but the `div` with the id "testContainer" in the second example.

Because `testContainer` has a fixed position and no other content, it will not have any width. Give it an explicit width and it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! This makes the progressbar visible, but it still appears on the left side of the page, rather than being fixed in the upper-right-hand corner. Any idea why?

Comment: Give your `top` and `right` properties a unit. The value `6` on its own won't work; it needs to be something like `6px`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a width for div#testcontainer.

Comment: I added "width : 20%" to the style for #testContainer, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I tested with FF and IE8, it worked. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oops, I was just missing a semicolon. Now the progress bar shows up, but it is displayed on the left side of the page, rather than the right.

Comment: I edited your css and used top : 6px;right : 6px;  (with "px"), and it worked